# Can't find variable: geoplugin_countryCode - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, redirect, geoip, country

I am having trouble to get my visitor's location and redirect him to the right website.

I am running one English website and one French. I need to redirect French visitors to French website and all others to the English one.

I want to use geoplugin and here is the code I wrote (inside the head tags) on the EN website :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"></script>

  <script>
    if(geoplugin_countryCode() == 'FR'){
        location.href = "//fr.mywebsite.com";
        }        
  </script>
```

The code written on the FR website :

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"></script>

  <script>
    if(geoplugin_countryCode() != 'FR'){
        location.href = "//www.mywebsite.com";
        }        
  </script>
```

Now when running the browser tells me that the variable geoplugin_countryCode can't be found.

I guess that something's wrong with the code, so if anyone has a solution it would be great !

Thanks in advance, Fabien

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution!

Since the store is http secure, I had to use the SSL web service and everything works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You are entering in an infinite loop.
What you should do is:
-check on your EN website, if the code is FR then redirect to FR website.
-Check on your FR website, if the code is not FR then redirect to EN website.

EN Website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"></script>

<script>
  if(geoplugin_countryCode() == 'FR'){
      location.href = "//fr.mywebsite.com";
  }       
</script>
```

FR Website:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp"></script>

<script>
  if(geoplugin_countryCode() != 'FR'){
      location.href = "//www.mywebsite.com";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Ok thanks, it makes sense. The loop is corrected but my browser still says that it cannot find the variable geoplugin_countryCode() so the redirection is not effective.

Comment: Firefox's Console tells me: Loading failed for the <script> with source “http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp”. Is running the websites through Shopify could be the problem ?